# Deaserializing parent JSON data in C# RootObject

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

Can someone help me figure out how to get the parent data in JSON data in C# using this sample code?

```
 string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message["data"]);
                //Deserialize to strongly typed class i.e., RootObject
                RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSON);

                //loop through the list and show on console
                foreach (Result resultsItem in obj.results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(resultsItem.shipping + "-" + resultsItem.model + "-" + resultsItem.price +
                           "-" + resultsItem.product_name);

                }
```

and root object class looks like this

```
public class Result
{
    public string shipping { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public string availability { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> cookies { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string connectorGuid { get; set; }
    public string connectorVersionGuid { get; set; }
    public string pageUrl { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}
```

I was able to write code to show column in Result class but I don't know how to reach to "PageUrl" in rootobject class. I tried all possible names in the foreach loop but columns in RootObject are just not accessible. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you get in `obj.pageUrl` ? Is it a null value ?

Comment: It is not null. it should show url link.

Comment: Eventually, I want to insert all the columns of Result and pageURL from the rootobject in a table. That's why I am trying to get all in one foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you needed?

```
foreach (Result resultsItem in obj.results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(resultsItem.shipping 
                      + "-" + resultsItem.model 
                      + "-" + resultsItem.price 
                      + "-" + resultsItem.product_name 
                      + "-" + obj.pageUrl);

}
```

This code will display `pageUrl` for each line of result.